# MySQL multiple databases and users

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on a MySQL project website with the goal that it could be implemented in several local companies in order to keep track of some information (note this is a project for a college course).  My question is about the best way to use a similar structure that can keep each company's info private from the others.

Assume I have 3 different companies, each requiring a database to store Employees, Projects, and Messages, or 3 DBs per company.

My current plan is to create 10 total databases: 3 of the 3 required databases for a total of 9.  These DBs would have a prefix to their name to differentiate them (e.g. `CompanyA_employees`, `CompanyB_employees`, `CompanyC_employees`, etc.) I would then use the 10th DB to store the company names and their respective prefixes. Is this a good way to do this, or is there a better way?

Also, I am also thinking to give each DB its own user (again, it would be prefixed) with its own unique password.  This would be the username and password that is used in a PHP script to access the DBs and `SELECT`, `INSERT`, etc.  My hope is that this would make it difficult for someone to compromise more than 1 DB at a time, or for companies to be able to access each others' sensitive information.  In addition, these users would only be given the bare minimum permissions to the DB, to further guard against things getting fubar'd.

I would store the DB users' passwords (`SHA256` or `SHA512` hashed with salt, of course) in that 10th DB.  If this is a good design, is there a better (but still secure) way to obtain these passwords than querying the 10th DB every time I need to access one of the other DBs?  I'm assuming storing them in a cookie is a bad idea security-wise.

Any suggestions are appreciated, as I am relatively new to securing MySQL DBs.

Comment: I understand going with separate DBs for separate companies, but why 3 DBs for a single company? Just do one masterDB, and then one DB per company.

Comment: It really depends... you could also isolate the DB from the companies and only allow access to an API. You will have finer granularity on who can access what and how many times.

Comment: I can probably throw everything into a single DB per company @RobbyCornelissen. My main goal for separating them was to allow for 3 users that would have unique passwords, making it more difficult for someone to hack and steal all the company info. I will have to see if one DB per company is possible, since there might be size limitation on the DB and our design has to scale to 1000+ companies. But thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you want to define more of a role that the databases are going to serve.

It really depends on the magnitude of the information expected to be held if you should have one database per company or one master database.

Note that most web hosts would not allow you to host 1000+ databases unless you are running your own dedicated database server. Cost definitely becomes a factor there.

For Employees, Projects, and Messages, one database should be sufficient.

Using the web interface, you only need the single database-user for the website itself to connect to the database. It is then up to how your website handles the website-user logins and what data each user has access to.

So for this you need to create a website-user-table in the database that handles the user login information, timeouts, intruder detection, and what information in the database that user has access to.

For each table of information, for example, you can have a single column with a unique company ID. Your website then allows a user that belongs to that company to see the information for that company and no other.

So your tables for the database will probably be:

---------
Web_Users
Company
Employees
Projects
Messages
---------

With the Web_users, Employees, Projects, and Messages tables linking to Company table using a foreign key.

This setup keeps your database secure because only your website can access it, and only those who can log into your website can then access information--only the information that belongs to the company that the user belongs to.

This puts the majority of the security burden on how well you write the website interface.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, very thorough and extremely helpful!  Much appreciated!

Comment: So as it turns out, I need to have a separate DB for each company. Would you suggest having one DB user for each DB, or just have one overall DB user that my website uses to access all of the databases?

Comment: Is there any reason that each company would have to do direct queries to their database? Or will your website be the only interface that connects to the database?

If you think of the website as a user itself, and all companies are going through the website, then you only need the database user for the website

Comment: Everything will be going through my website, so I will only have one user then.  Thanks a lot for all the help!